# TYPO3 make fe_user registration on 3 steps

Tags: typo3

dear friends! I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and fe_manager extension. I need make front end user registration on three steps.

1 step: Registration with email, username and password.

2 step: filling profile

3 step: uploading profile photo.

Do you have any idea? Is it possible ? Can anybody help me with good idea, or may be with some code! I would be very thankful !

Answer (score 1):

please check this extension: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_feuser_register. This is mostly used for this type of registration. You can edit the template to have it in 3 steps and maybe need to extend it in your own extension for profile photo field.

I think you will find several tutorials how to do this whole thing if you won't mange to do it alone.

Comment: EXT:sr_feuser_register uses old templating mechanism with markers, has hardcoded html snippets in php classes and lot of dependencies to other extensions.

Comment: Yes man. I already saw it(( It's bad way( May be you can tell me something useful ?